# Read a file with both string and double to draw rectangle

Tags: java, swing, java.util.scanner, java-2d

I have a input file-file.txt with below contents

> ```
> M1 100 100 400.89 400.72   
>   400 400 450.89 450.72
> ```
>
> M2 100 100 440.56 440.82
>       M3 100 200 300.52 330.75
>          200 200 320.53 340.34
>           300 300 400.43 350.25

I have written a program to draw a rectangle.But I am not able to draw it for M1,M2 and M3   simultaneously.The four double values in each line represent the 2 coordinates of a rectangle. Also please help me out in solving this if in case my file is

> M1 = [ 100 100 400.89 400.72;
>    400 400 450.89 450.72 ]
>   M2 = [100 100 440.56 440.82 ]
>   M3 = [100 200 300.52 330.75;
>    200 200 320.53 340.34;
>    300 300 400.43 350.25]

The code I have written is:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat.*;

class Rectangles extends JComponent
{
 public void paint(Graphics g)

 { 
 Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
   try
  {

   File x=new File("file.txt");
   Scanner sc=new Scanner(x);
 while(sc.hasNext())
 { 
  String s=sc.next();
 if(s.equals("M1"))
  {
 while(sc.hasNext())
  {
  double x1=sc.nextDouble();
  double y1=sc.nextDouble();
  double x3=sc.nextDouble();
  double y3=sc.nextDouble();
  double x2=x3;
  double y2=y1;
  double x4=x1;
  double y4=y3;
  double a=x1;
  double b=y1;
  double c1=Math.sqrt((x2-x1)*(x2-x1)+(y2-y1)*(y2-y1));
  double d1=Math.sqrt((x4-x1)*(x4-x1)+(y4-y1)*(y4-y1));
  double c=c1;
  double d=d1;
  g2.setPaint(Color.blue);
  g2.draw(new Rectangle2D.Double(a,b,c,d));
  g2.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(a,b,c,d)); 

  }

  }
  }}      

   catch(Exception e)
    {
   System.out.println("reported Exception");
     }

   }
   }


   public class eighth
   {

  public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException
  {

   JFrame window = new JFrame();
   window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   window.setBounds(60, 60, 900, 900);
    window.getContentPane().add(new Rectangles());
    window.setVisible(true);

   }
  }
```

How to draw the three rectangles of type M1, M2 and M3 simultaneously?

Comment: There is no '?' in that post.  What is your question?

Comment: my question is how to draw the three rectangles of type M1, M2 and M3 simultaneously

Comment: 1) Thanks for adding a question (but don't forget to add a '?').  2) Now I look at the question and code, I recommend you establish a `BufferedImage` in a `Rectangles` constructor, store it as a class attribute then read/parse the input files and draw them to the image.  Display the image in a `JLabel`.  No need to extend anything, and it would probably solve your question.

Comment: "Swing programs should override `paintComponent()` instead of overriding `paint()`."—[*Painting in AWT and Swing: The Paint Methods*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#callbacks).

Answer (score 2):

- read `File` outside `paint()`, prepare that before,
- because `paint()` could be fired a few times per second, then FIleIO can freeze whole GUI

  a) from `Mouse` and `KeyBoard` event

  b) `JComponent` firing events internally, when `repaint()` is required
- use `paintComponent()` instead of `paint()` for `JComponent`
- put all `Char`s in to `List` or `ArrayList`,
- inside `paintComponent()` to loop inside array by using `Graphics2D.drawString()`

---

- why bothering with `painting in JComponent`, put `String` to the `JLabel` or `JTextArea`
- change `BackGround`
- for `JLabel` have to `setOpaque(true)`, because `JLabel` is transparent

Comment: can you explain me in detail by writing the code you want to suggest.Thank you!!